# InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable?

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, audiocontext, audiobuffer

i have an app that's creating an audio context and then decoding multiple audio files to get audio buffers on page load (on component mount in react) ,
everything is going as expected , handling errors and all .

but there's one that i don't know its source :

**InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable**

after some research i found out that the audio context is starting with a state of suspended , and that's what's causing the problem .

is that gonna affect the app or not ?